# ASIHTTPRequest Cache is crashing app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I have the following code:

```
+ (NSMutableArray*)getTodayData:(NSDate*)today
{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ichrono/20110715/60b88126/load_dr_daily_schedule/%@/", [self getDrChronoHost], [dateFormat stringFromDate:today]]];

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
        [self addCurrentUserLoginToPostRequest:request];        
        [request setPostValue:[dateFormat stringFromDate:today] forKey:@"target_date"];
        [request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
        [request startSynchronous];

        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSString *responseString;
        if (!error) {
            responseString = [request responseString];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
        return [responseString JSONValue];
    }
}
```

It worked fine before I added the line `[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];`.

How I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ASIFormDataRequest setDownloadCache:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a0140'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `setDownloadCache` is not instance method defined in `ASIFormDataRequest`.

As per `ASIHTTPRequest` documentation:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_a_download_cache

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
```

Your exception says it all "`'-[ASIFormDataRequest setDownloadCache:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a0140`"

Comment: So is there anyway I can setup a cache with ASIFormDataRequest?

Comment: So what alternative do I have to cahce the data? Its being parsed with JSON as well.

Comment: [ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]]; adding the above line might help. Am not familiar with ASIHTTPRequest. Never used this API before.